# Vertical align html5 fullscreen video with custom controls

Tags: css, html, video

I was looking for a nice themed html5 video player and beside jwplayer, I found the project Videre on Github https://github.com/Hipady/Videre

I forked the code and removed some stuff I don't need. But I wasn't able yet to get fullscreen working with my custom video controls.

Here's a test page: https://onny.project-insanity.org/files/videre-html5-videoplayer-test/index.html
Here's the source code: https://git.project-insanity.org/onny/web-videre-diet

And here's a screenshot showing the issue:
[image]

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to vertically center the video in fullscreen :(

The issue could be related to this part of the CSS:

```
.vid-wrapper {
  position: relative; }
[...]
  .vid-wrapper .vid-html5 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; }
    .vid-wrapper .vid-html5 video {
      display: block;
      background-color: black; }
```

Firefox and Chrome seem to behave differently in this case and it seems that only Firefox has this issue.

Best regards,
Jonas

Comment: Your own test page shows it centered fine in fullscreen mode (at least in a Chromium-based browser.)

Comment: Also, please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into the question, not just on external sites.

Comment: @CBroe: Than maybe this issue is related to Firefox?

Comment: Maybe, but that’s rather what you should have figured out before asking - so that you can then explicitly mention this in your question, so that other people don’t have to go, _huh, whasse onnabout ...?_

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify that in my question. I added it.